# How to add a custom callback on-slide for UI sliders using Angular directives?

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, callback, angularjs-directive

I'm beginning with Angular.js directives, and in any application, I'm using jQuery UI sliders.

What I would to do is to execute a custom callback on the slide event of these sliders, depending of the slider, because I have more than one in the page.

I made a JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zWHyM/

And basically, this is the directive I "wrote", inspired of some Google Discussion threads that I found.

HTML:

```
<section id='app'>
    <aside id='settings' ng-controller='SettingsCtrl'>
        <form name='settings-form' method='post' action='#' ng-submit='generate()'>
            <h4 class='settings-title'>Settings</h4>
            <h5>Quality <span id='quality-value' class='info'>1</span></h5>
            <div id='quality' class='slider slider-range' min='1' max='3' step='1' value='1' ui-slider></div>
            <h6 id='quality-label' class='label info'>Take care of this point: increase the quality level needs a lot of resources from your computer, it may slow it down or crash this website.</h6>
            <h5>rotation <span id='rotation-value' class='info'>0</span></h5>
            <div id='rotation' class='slider slider-range' min='0' max='360' step='1' value='0' ui-slider></div>
            <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Hyperlapse it !' />
        </form>
    </aside>
</section>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp.directive', []).directive('uiSlider', function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.slider({
            value: parseInt(attrs.value),
            min: parseInt(attrs.min),
            max: parseInt(attrs.max),
            step: parseInt(attrs.step),
            slide: function (e, ui) {
                // So here I can get the value with ui.value,
                // But how to execute a custom callback, depending on the slider ?
                // For instance, I am trying to update an element with the value
                // $('#quality-value').text(ui.value) for the quality slider
                // $('#rotation-value').text(ui.value) for the rotation slider.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I would appreciate any suggestion/advice on this point !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/cJRCW/

A quick solution is to pass the name of a callback as an attribute to the directive, with the assumption this will be a function available in the local scope.

**In your template:**

```
<div id='quality' class='slider slider-range' min='1' max='30' step='1' value='1' callback='callback1' ui-slider></div>
```

**In your controller:**

```
$scope.callback1 = function() {
    console.log('callback1 called');   
}

$scope.callback2 = function() {
    console.log('callback2 called');
}
```

**In your directive:**

```
slide: function (e, ui) {
    scope[attrs.callback]();
}
```

Comment: Aha, I was thinking to something like that but shame on me that I didn't realize I could access the scope relative to the controller... Thanks a lot !